# How to update the WCF Service Reference in .NET CORE Web project?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core

I have added the WCF Service reference by

> **Service References --> Add Connected Service --> WCF Service Preview**

Its working fine, Service reference added successfully.
Now I have modified the WCF Service (added new web methods) and would like to update the Service Reference which I have arleady created.

In .net framework project I was able to achieve by clicking on "Update Service Reference" . Do we have this feature in .NET CORE Project?

Comment: Support for WCF in .NET CORE is limited at this point - you may need to delete the reference and add it again.

Comment: Tim, thats a pain, I have more than 10 service references. Each service update, i have to delete and add reference.

Comment: I don't know if you can do this in .NET CORE, but what I've done with our large application that has multiple services is abandoned the "Add Service Reference" approach, and use `ChannelFactory<T>` to create the proxy and any needed channels to the service.  The contracts (interfaces) used for `<T>` are maintained in a separate assembly that is shared with the consuming clients and service implementations.   This way, when a service definition changes I just need to ensure the updated contracts assembly is deployed as well.

Comment: @sivaL Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 16):

Right click on the **folder icon** that contains your ConnectedService.json

[image]

Comment: There is currently a [bug][2] that gives `Version for package `dotnst-svcutil` could not be resolved` in the preview version of Core 2.1.

Comment: That option does not exist in VS2022

Comment: In VS2022 - > Project menu -> Connected Services -> Manage Connected Services. From '...' menu on service reference, select Edit and go through steps to regenerate.

Comment: If not generated via Visual Studio or alternatively to generate via command line, can use `dotnet-svcutil`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the connected service again with the exact same Namespace. Don't delete the existing one. It will overwrite it automatically.
I just did it and connected to a different instance of my service and it recreated the entire reference.

Comment: I just tried it, using net core 2.0, and it worked for me. Added service and used the same namespace, it asked if i was sure i wanted to replace Reference.cs, confirmed and it worked, my service's new method has been added correctly.

Comment: Mine for some reason is not recreating the reference.cs file, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is to promote tjmoore's reply:

In VS2022 - > Project menu -> Connected Services -> Manage Connected Services. From '...' menu on service reference, select Edit and go through steps to regenerate. –
tjmoore
Nov 11, 2022 at 16:46

Answer (score 0):

IF your WCF URL is changed follow the below.

Navigate to "projectfolder\Connected Services\servicename\ConnectedService.json"
Edit the json file

```
"ExtendedData": {
    "inputs": [
      "https://example.com/apis.asmx" (put your new url and save)
    ],
```

Then follow the steps below.
In VS2022 - > Project menu -> Connected Services -> Manage Connected Services. From '...' menu on service reference, select Edit and go through steps to regenerate Reference.cs.

or you can do this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x

Comment: simmilar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75672108/wcf-update-service-references-from-cli